# How to enable the MySQL Slow query log (5.5.15)

Tags: mysql

Need some help. I've looked around topics here on stack and on mysql's website and none of the configurations ever work for me. I need to enable the MySQL slow query log as well as teh general query log. I want to do it in my config file rather than as a `SET` statement because I assume that would reset whenever mysql was rebooted?

What am I missing?! Every site says something completely different... I'm using MySQL 5.5.15. This is my current config:

```
[mysqld]
local-infile=0
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
user=mysql
skip-external-locking

query_cache_limit=8M
query_cache_size=64M
query_cache_type=1

long_query_time=2
slow_query_log_file=/var/log/mysqld.slow.log

max_connections=100
max_user_connections=10
interactive_timeout=20
wait_timeout=20
connect_timeout=6

thread_cache_size=128
key_buffer=16M
key_buffer_size=256M

join_buffer=1M
max_allowed_packet=16M
table_cache=1024
read_buffer_size=2M
sort_buffer_size=2M
max_connect_errors=10

# Try number of CPU's*2 for thread_concurrency
thread_concurrency=4
myisam_sort_buffer_size=64M

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `slow_query_log=1` to your config file.

[Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/slow-query-log.html)

Comment: GENIUS! For some reason when I tried using that before mysql failed to start up again >_<... Do you know how to turn the general query log on as well and specify the file?

Comment: `general_log=1` and `general_log_file=/var/log/mysqld.general.log`

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/query-log.html

Comment: why 1?  is that milliseconds? why not 5 or 10?

Comment: @Rick - it's just a boolean on or off. Valid values are 0 or 1.